# Why I am getting this error: constexpr' is not valid here

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2015, constexpr

I have this code:

```
class myClass
{
        constexpr int x = 4;
};
```

and on visual studio 2015, I am getting this error:

```
'constexpr' is not valid here
```

Why I am getting this error? I want a const static variable that I can initlaize it on header file.

In the next step I want to change my class to a template, but this constant is not related to the type of clas.

Comment: *"I want a const static variable..."* then why not declare it `static`?

Comment: @CinCout I thought that since it is a constant expression, then there is no need to define it as static. How a const expression can be non static?

Comment: @mans that's in global scope. In global scope and in class they have different meaning

Comment: @Swift What is the difference? Can you please elaborate? In a class scope, how a variable can be const but not static?

Comment: it will be const , but  not unique for class instance, it would be still part of instance and would require context. It becomes const when instance constructed and is initialized then (can be set in initialization list of constructor). static member  (regardless of const or not) is created and initialized at some point when program is started (undefined at which point, just guaranteed to be initialized before any  object is created). A const static member can't be changed afterwards, that's all, it's still created only once. For global scope static keyword just specifies local linkage of id.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Non-`static` data members cannot be declared as `constexpr`. Use

```
class myClass
{
    static constexpr int x = 4;
};
```

instead.

Answer (score 2):

> > I want a const static variable that I can initlaize it on header file

if your main concern is constant value which is shareable to all template type instances, then you can just change to the below:

```
class myClass
{
    static const int x = 4;
};
```

If your concern is the memory space (although it is shared between all instances), you can just use compilation pre-processing solution (i.e. #Define X 4)